# Rewrite single method using local class

Tags: overrides, class, extend

I need to override Varien class because I need to change one method.

```
app/code/core/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
```

From what I know, the only way is to put it inside local folder.

```
app/code/local/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
```

But in this way I override entire class. Is there any way to override just single method?

Comment: *Which method are you trying to override, and why??* Many of these methods are overridden in the Magento collection superclasses.

Comment: Explain what you try to achieve. I'm sure there is a better method than overwriting a core class.

Comment: Method getSelectCountSql() because I use group by in admin grid and this returns wrong count. Unfortunately I could not find any better way. See [using group() breaks getSelectCountSql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485455/using-group-breaks-getselectcountsql-in-magento) and [Wrong count in admin Grid when using GROUP BY clause](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/01/05/magento-wrong-count-in-admin-grid-when-using-group-by-clause-overriding-lib-module/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `getSelectCountSql()` is overwritten in a lot of collections like 
`Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` for example.

So if you need to change the behavior of `getSelectCountSql()` for some collection, you can easily do that in your collection class.

But do not do that in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` because it will change the behavior of this method for all collections.

Comment: You are right, I extended Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection class and it works. tnx!

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

The original definition for this class lives in the *`./lib/Varien/`* folder.

If you *must* override any autoloaded classes from the *`./lib`* folder, you can only do this via inclusion *in total* in one of the codepools (local, core, community in order of precedence).

There is no way to overwrite only one method.